# Problem when i open second form from datagridview button in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have two forms. First is the dashboard form (Form 1) which contains a datagridview with a button column for each row which opens a second form (Form 2) with the order details of the selected datagridview row. Everything works fine when it shows all records from the database, the button opens the Form 2 with all the details, id and everything. When i filter the datagridview by client or date or something else, i get the desired rows (clients, date etc), but if i click again on the edit button, i get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

It is like the filtering changes something in the code or query but i can't figure out what, basicaly it is the same row, same data, but filtered.

Code of Form 1:

```
private void GridComenzi_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            String colname = GridComenzi.Columns[GridComenzi.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;
            DataGridViewRow row = this.GridComenzi.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            if (colname == "Edit")
            {

                string editOrder = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                Editare ed = new Editare(editOrder);
                ed.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Code of Form 2:

```
public Editare(string editOrder)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            EditOrderList.View = View.Details;
            EditOrderList.FullRowSelect = true;

            DataTable dt = GetOrderDetails(editOrder);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    EditOrderList.Items.Add(dr["Denumire"].ToString());
                    EditOrderList.Items[EditOrderList.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(dr["Cantitate"].ToString());
                    EditOrderList.Items[EditOrderList.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(dr["Dimensiuni"].ToString());
                    EditOrderList.Items[EditOrderList.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(dr["Comentarii"].ToString());
                    EditOrderList.Items[EditOrderList.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(dr["NumeMaterial"].ToString());
                    EditOrderList.Items[EditOrderList.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(dr["NumeFinisaj"].ToString());



                    if (dr["Livstatus"].ToString() == "Livrata")
                    {
                        radioLiv.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        radioNeliv.Checked = true;
                    }

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sdatime = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT OrderID, Clienti.NumeClient, Produse.Denumire, Produse.Cantitate, Produse.Dimensiuni, Produse.Comentarii, Produse.NumeMaterial, Produse.NumeFinisaj, IDComenzi.DataInitial,Comenzi.DataFinalizare, Comenzi.Factstatus, Comenzi.Livstatus FROM Comenzi INNER JOIN Clienti ON Comenzi.ClientID = Clienti.IDClient INNER JOIN Produse ON Comenzi.ProductID = Produse.IDProdus INNER JOIN IDComenzi ON Comenzi.OrderID = IDComenzi.IDComanda WHERE OrderID=@OrderID", con))
                    {
                        sdatime.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = editOrder; // ALSO POSSIBLE ERROR HERE (i didn't get this far)
                        DataTable dtTime = new DataTable();
                        sdatime.Fill(dtTime);
                        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTime.Rows[0]["DataInitial"].ToString());
                        dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTime.Rows[0]["DataFinalizare"].ToString());
                        NrComanda.Text = (dtTime.Rows[0]["OrderID"].ToString());
                        NumCl.Text = (dtTime.Rows[0]["NumeClient"].ToString());
                        if (dtTime.Rows[0]["Factstatus"].ToString() == "Nefacturata")
                        {
                            radioNefact.Checked = true;
                            TextFactura.Text = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TextFactura.Text = (dtTime.Rows[0]["Factstatus"].ToString());
                            radioNefact.Checked = false;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            if (Connection.type == "C")
            {
                tableLayoutPanel1.Enabled = false;
                tableLayoutPanel2.Enabled = false;
                tableLayoutPanel5.Enabled = false;
                EditOrderList.Enabled = false;
                UpdateOrder.Enabled = false;
            }

        }

public DataTable GetOrderDetails(string editOrder)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = GAMEWORK\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Tida; Integrated Security = True"))
            using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Clienti.NumeClient, Produse.Denumire, Produse.Cantitate, Produse.Dimensiuni, Produse.Comentarii, Produse.NumeMaterial, Produse.NumeFinisaj, IDComenzi.DataInitial,Comenzi.DataFinalizare, Comenzi.Factstatus, Comenzi.Livstatus FROM Comenzi INNER JOIN Clienti ON Comenzi.ClientID = Clienti.IDClient INNER JOIN Produse ON Comenzi.ProductID = Produse.IDProdus INNER JOIN IDComenzi ON Comenzi.OrderID = IDComenzi.IDComanda WHERE OrderID=@OrderID", con))
            {
                ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(editOrder); //ERROR HERE: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ada.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `editOrder` is at that point?

Comment: I am sorry, i do not understand. What and how should i check?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that is giving the error (press F9), when execution stop there then hover mouse over `editOrder` and it will tell you what the value is. You will see if it can be converted to `int`

Comment: The value shown is   "118"

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/YV3X1J, perhaps there is a space or an unprintable character in the text

Comment: It does not seem to be any problem with spaces or unprintable chars. Now i noticed that when i insert the order details from another form, it is the same problem. It seems it only works if it retrieves all data from database. Any changes from outside the retrieve query which fills the datagridview, breaks the button functionality.

Comment: I managed to make it work by using the value in the id column. Thank for your help :)